# How to merge multiple(more than 2) csv files based on their common column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Now I have 50 CSV files with the same column like below:

gdp1950.csv

```
id,gdp
a,100
b,200
c,300
```

gdp1951.csv

```
id,gdp
a,400
b,500
c,600
```

...

gdp2000.csv

```
id,gdp
a,700
b,800
c,900
```

What I am going to do is merge the csv files above like this:

```
id,gdp1950,gdp1951,...,gdp2000
a,100,400,...,700
b,200,500,...,800
c,300,600,...,900
```

The task are required to be done in jupyter notebook by Python. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep. Code it. Put all your filenames in a list. Create a dictionary with `a` through to `c` as keys and empty lists as values. Create a key `header` with value `["id",]` loop over your list of filenames. Read in every file using your list of filenames, parse the values, add them to the list at key ["a".."c"] - add the filename to the value of key ["header"]. Then write the parsed data out. Come back if you have specific problems - SO is no code writing service. Thanks.

Comment: Why not try `pandas` `merge`

Comment: @Wen-Ben I oriented myself at the tags - I wont code it for him/her - no tag with pandas. It is a no effort shown question without any problem statement - and hence to broad to be answered.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I agree with you , so that I just provide the general idea and let him/her self figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library called [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org), which is perfect for this task:

```
from functools import reduce
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f"gdp{i}.csv") for i in range(1950, 2001)]
df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=["id"], how="inner"), dfs)
```

Comment: Your code names the columns `gdpx` and `gdpy`, not the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using vanilla python, no need of third-party libraries nor modules:

```
outputDict = {"id" : []}
for i in range(1950, 2001):
    outputDict["id"].append(f"gdp{i}")
    with open(f"gdp{i}.csv", "r") as file:
        file.readline()    # We don't need that line
        for line in file:
            key, value = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
            if key in outputDict:
                outputDict[key].append(value)
            else:
                outputDict[key] = [value]

with open("gdpTotal.csv", "w") as output:
     output.write("\n".join(",".join((k, *[i for i in v])) for k, v in outputDict.items()))    # Convert the dictionary of lists into a suitable string for file writing
```

The last line `"\n".join(",".join((k, *[i for i in v])) for k, v in outputDict.items())` is something equivalent to (the result is the same but the process isn't)

```
for k, v in outputDict.items():
    output.write(f"{k},{','.join(v)}\n")
```

Also, you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to remove the if statement. In addition, it's slightly faster.

```
outputDict = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(1950, 2001):
    outputDict["id"].append(f"gdp{i}")
    with open(f"gdp{i}.csv", "r") as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            key, value = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
            outputDict[key].append(value)

with open("gdpTotal.csv", "w") as output:
     output.write("\n".join(",".join((k, *[i for i in v])) for k, v in outputDict.items()))
```

Using [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) (with the parameter `number = 100`) it takes `0.825195171` seconds the first code (`0.8229198819999999` the second code).
Instead the usage of pandas:

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f"gdp{i}.csv") for i in range(1950, 2001)]
df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=["id"], how="inner"), dfs)
df.to_csv("gdpTotal.csv")
```

Takes `32.095738075999996` seconds. It may take fewer lines but it's much slower.